# How permanently disable keyboard backlight on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, backlight, keyboard-backlight

I have installed Ubuntu on `Gigabyte Aorus pro B560M` motherboard. It worked fine at first but then and after resetting the BIOS(to fix a networking issue) now it has an annoying behavior of keyboard backlight is blinking all the time.

I've looked into the mobo BIOS setting but could not find anything pertinent to keyboard backlight. The manual was not helpful either.

So I'm wondering how can I disable this pesky backlight permanently at OS level?

Comment: Hello. Your keyboard probably comes with some software that only works on Windows. Look into that.

Comment: Did you tinker with a bunch of stuff in bios???(if so) if you know the network issue fix now, reset the bios back to factory settings(if it doesn't cause too much pain), and see if it goes away. Then re-apply your network issue fix.

Comment: I did reset the bios (by pulling out battery and connecting the junctions) but the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have another computer available? Ensure it's not just doing that all that time now, regardless of what PC it is plugged in? And are you sure you don't have that setting in your bios? that might be one of those RGB settings, maybe you previously had disabled? (I'm no expert on that though... that's something that's hot with 'the cool kids' these days)... What bios version do you have? I have a gigabyte motherboard on one of my machines

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/625650/143980) can help you configure a init script or systemd script to be automatically executed at boot time and then set keyboard backlight brigthness to 0 every time that you (re)boot your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but one option might be:

Download and use https://openrgb.org/releases.html

Comment: Well, I've installed that but not sure how can I use it to shut down all lighting. Any hints about that?

Comment: You need to check the documents of openrgb, and compare to what hardware your computer contains. This will likely reveal what to do. I'm expecting this to differ compared to what I had to do on my Asus laptop.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I just tried this and it works for Ubuntu 22.04.

```
cd /sys/class/leds/platform::kbd_backlight
sudoedit brightness
```

and turn the value to 0